# Handle the DataContext in EntityFramework 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-access

Is there any "best practice" on how to handle the Datacontext in Entity Framework 4?

Currently, I'm doing something like this in **every** window:

```
public class MyWindow()
{
    MyEntities() _entities;
    MyWindow()
    {
        _entities = new MyEntities();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and then the loading into a datagrid like this:

```
    myGrid.ItemsSource= _entities.MyTable;
```

This is not really clever, because ErrorHandling is made impossible on that.

I'd rather go for a Connection-Class and do something like this:

```
public class MyData()
{
    public IQueryable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
           return context.Products;
        }
    }
}
```

But first, this creates a new context-instance **every** time - isn't this bad?

Or should I rather handle a global static DataContext in my Connection-Class? Doesn't get this static variable very overloaded?

```
public class MyData()
{
    private static MyContext Context = new MyContext();
    public IQueryable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
      return Context.Products;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read Myth#10 - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/10linqmyths.aspx , Hope this helps.

Comment: Group your methods into 'units of work', so that creating a new context each time is logical - the context should only exist as long as a unit of work is ongoing.

Comment: Okay, so there is no problem to have a DataContext in every window, that just passes itself to my Connection-Class (just for Exception-Handling cases)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In entity framework, an `ObjectContext`/`DbContext` is a unit of work, their lifetime is meant to be short.

Having a static context is a definite no-no, as this would use a lot of memory with change tracking entities (every change tracked entity would be cached and stored until the context is disposed).

Wrapping the context in a using, like your 'Connection-Class' example is the right way to go about doing this. This would often be referred to as a Service.

An example service:

```
public class ProductService
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            foreach(var product in context.Products)
                yield return product;
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to call either `ToArray()` or `ToList()` or use `yield return`(as in my example) when returning a collection of results in a block where the context will be disposed. Failing to do this would mean that when your results are used, deferred execution will attempt to use the disposed context which will result in an exception at runtime.